# Append queried Recordset to Table in Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am querying Active Directory to list Users and other fields in Access. Is there a way to append my queried results into an existing table? Currently I am trying to use INSERT INTO but having issues with my Object variable not being set or block variable.

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()

Dim objRecordSet As Object
Dim objCommand As Object
Dim objConnection As Object
Dim dbs As Database

Const ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE = 2

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
objConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
objConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
Set objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection

objCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 1000
objCommand.Properties("Searchscope") = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE
objCommand.Properties("Sort On") = "whenCreated"

objCommand.CommandText = _
"SELECT Name,Title,PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName,WhenCreated,Mail FROM 'LDAP://OU=Standard Users,OU=Active Users,OU=All Users,DC=contoso,dc=local' WHERE objectCategory='user'"
Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute

objRecordSet.MoveFirst
Do Until objRecordSet.EOF
  dbs.Execute " INSERT INTO ADUsers" & "(Name,Title,Site,Created,Email) VALUES " & "(objRecordSet.Fields('Name').Value,objRecordSet.Fields('Title').Value,objRecordSet.Fields('physicalDeliveryOfficeName').Value,objRecordSet.Fields('whenCreated').Value,objRecordSet.Fields('Mail').Value);"
  dbs.Close
  Debug.Print objRecordSet.Fields("Name").Value; "," & objRecordSet.Fields("Title").Value; "," & objRecordSet.Fields("physicalDeliveryOfficeName").Value; "," & objRecordSet.Fields("whenCreated").Value; "," & objRecordSet.Fields("Mail").Value

objRecordSet.MoveNext

Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything inside doublequotes `"` is interpreted as string not as code and strings (the values of `objRecordSet.Fields("myFieldName").Value`) have to be quoted in insert statement.

```vb
dim strSQLInsert as String

strSQLInsert = "INSERT INTO ADUsers(Name,Title,Site,Created,Email) VALUES ('" & _ 
  objRecordSet.Fields("Name").Value & "','" & _
  objRecordSet.Fields("Title").Value & "','" & 
  objRecordSet.Fields("physicalDeliveryOfficeName").Value & "','" & _
  objRecordSet.Fields("whenCreated").Value & "','" & _
  objRecordSet.Fields("Mail").Value & "');"

Debug.Print strSQLInsert

dbs.Execute strSQLInsert
```

Store your sql statements in a string, then you can check it with `Debug.Print`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a parameterized query using [querydefs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177500(v=office.12).aspx) to avoid the need of quotes. Also be sure to initialize the database object which may be your main issue: `set dbs = CurrentDb`.

```
...
Dim strSQL As String
Set dbs = CurrentDb

strSQL = "PARAMETERS NameParm TEXT(255), TitleParam TEXT(255), SiteParam TEXT(255)," _
             & " CreatedParm Date, EmailParam TEXT(255);" _
             & " INSERT INTO ADUsers (Name, Title, Site, Created, Email)" _
             & " VALUES ([NameParm], [TitleParam], [SiteParam], [Created], [Email]);"

Do Until objRecordSet.EOF

   Set qdef = dbs.CreateQueryDef("", strSQL)

   qdef!NameParam = objRecordSet![Name]
   qdef!TitleParam = objRecordSet![Title]
   qdef!SiteParam = objRecordSet![PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName]
   qdef!CreatedParam = objRecordSet![WhenCreated]
   qdef!EmailParam = objRecordSet![Mail]

   qdef.Execute (dbfailOnError)
   Set qdef = Nothing

   objRecordSet.MoveNext
Loop
```